# Displaying a nice message box in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, messagebox

Does anyone knows a nice and simple message box that can be used in ASP.NET to display to the user to handle possible errors, and stuff like that...

I've tried the following code:

```
else{
         String csname1 = "PopupScript";
         String cstext1 = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                          "alert('Error adding product');</" + "script>";
         RegisterStartupScript(csname1, cstext1);
    }
```

It does what I want but its design is poor and terrible. Are there any other ways to display a little bit more fancy message box, maybe with some smooth transition ??

All help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're happy to use jquery, there's plenty of choice, eg [http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-msgbox/92626](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-msgbox/92626)

Comment: Try SweetAlert http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert

Comment: SweetAlert works just fine for what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at John Papa's [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).  It's a lightweight client-side notification plugin...

```
toastr.error('Error adding product', 'Error!')
```

You also have `toastr.info`, `toastr.success`, `toastr.warn`, which are all styled with appropriate colours.

There's a configurable [`demo here`](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) worth checking out, along with the demo in the comments.